# Adding buttons to toolbar programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a hard time adding a button to the toolbar in swift, below you can see an image of the toolbar that I'm after, unfortunately even though I have it designed in my Storyboard file, it doesn't show up when setting the toolbar to be  visible.

The way that I have designed this is two items, the first being a `flexable space` element, and the second being an `add` element. It looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code that I've used to attempt to replicate this in code:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
self.navigationController?.toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem]()
self.navigationController?.toolbarItems?.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
)
self.navigationController?.toolbarItems?.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "onClickedToolbeltButton:")
)
```

As you can see I'm setting the toolbar to be visible, initializing (and clearing) the toolbarItems array of UIBarButtonItem, and then adding two UIBarButtonItem's to the array, in the proper order.

However, the toolbelt remains empty, why is this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The usual way to do that is to create the array of toolbar items and then assign the array to the `items` property of the toolbar.

```
self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
)
items.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(onClickedToolbeltButton(_:)))
)
toolbarItems = items
```

Comment: If action is nil, why do you need to set target as self?

Comment: as @DavidSeek mentioned, `self.toolbarItems` on `UIViewController` is the right way to set toolbar buttons.

Comment: Oh, just know navigationController has a build-in `toolbar`, I created my own `toolbar` and set its constraints programmatically before, what a miss:)

Answer (score 45):

None of the above worked for me, but:

**Swift 3 / Swift 4**

```
self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil) )
items.append( UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(add)) ) // replace add with your function

self.toolbarItems = items // this made the difference. setting the items to the controller, not the navigationcontroller
```

Comment: This works, but the real question is what are the rest of them doing?

Comment: Those who scroll down will be rewarded.  Thank you.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead, but yes, what makes it different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 7):

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarItems = items

self.navigationController?.setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)

self.navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
```

**Try it.**

```
        self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        )
        items.append(
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "onClickedToolbeltButton:")
        )

        self.navigationController?.toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`:

```
navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
let barButtonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: self.mapView)
self.toolbarItems = [barButtonItem]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: "addSomething:")
toolbarItems = [UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),addButton]
self.navigationController!.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated answer using the current selector syntax for

### Swift 3

```
var barButtons = [UIBarButtonItem]()
barButtons.append(
    UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ThisViewController.onDoneBarButtonClick))
)
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(barButtons, animated: false)
```

You can place this code in any loading event. It works seamless for me in viewDidLoad().

Replace "ThisViewController.onDoneBarButtonClick" with your view controller class name and any method you want to write to manage the toolbar button click.