# Why setting the barItems is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have a UIViewController, and I embed it into a UINavigationController.

I want to show one item in the toolbar (and by toolbar, I mean [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW4):

This is my code in viewDidLoad method

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
self.navigationController?.toolbar.items?.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Buy Potato", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buyPotato)))
self.navigationController?.toolbarItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Buy Potato", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buyPotato)))     
self.toolbarItems?.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: "Buy Potato", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buyPotato)))
```

and I already have the method buyPotato

```
func buyPotato() {

    }
```

as you see, I tried to do that using either the viewController or the navigationController, but it doesn't work.

All I can see is the toolbar at the bottom of my screen but without any button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
items.append(
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Plain, target: self, action: nil))
items.append(
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "onClickedToolbeltButton:"))
self.setToolbarItems(barButtonItems, animated: true)
```

This has to work for you as per the answer written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106123/3921490).

Comment: Oh I am not taling about the navigation bar at all, I am taking about the toolbar, which is at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Please check the answer now @sarah

Comment: Edited as per your comment!

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Delete

```
self.setToolbarItems(barButtonItems, animated: true)
```

Add

```
self.toolbarItems = barButtonItems
```